# What is the purpose of 'Reservations' in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm just starting to explore amazon ec2. And I want to hear some explanations or may be some brief examples of how and why do you need 'reservations' in amazon ec2. I'm using python framework `boto` to manage Amazon Service. And so far I don't really see any reasons why do we have this extra step in order to get your instances, for example:

```
reservations = ec2.get_all_instances()
instances = [instance for res in reservations for instance in res.instances]
```

That's how I get all my instances, some times I do it like this:

```
reservation = ec2.run_instances(image_id, min_count, max_count, key_name .....)
instance = reservation.instances[0]
```

And than I use those instances to attach volumes, add tags, add security groups and so on.... But what is the purpose of `boto.ec2.instance.Reservation` (I'm not asking only about boto framework, of course its preferred, but in a whole meaning of this in Amazon EC2)

```
>>> reservation = reservations[0]
>>> reservation
Reservation:r-74d11509
>>> dir(reservation)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'connection', 'endElement', 'groups', 'id', 'instances', 'item', 'owner_id', 'region', 'startElement', 'stop_all']
>>> reservation.__class__
<class 'boto.ec2.instance.Reservation'>
```

I couldn't find any useful methods. Please explain me why do we need this? What's the reason it to be there? In what cases you would use it?

Comment: You could try `help(reservation)` as well.

Comment: @cyroxx thank you for pointing me to very useful command but, I still don't see the answer to my question.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From my understanding, a reservation is an *act* of launching instances. Basically, a reservation is what you *do*, while an instance is what you *get*. If you launch multiple instances from one image via `run_instances()` you make one reservation, but get multiple instances.

`run_instances` together with `Reservation.stop_all()` allows you to run a bunch of instances, wait for them to complete the task and then stop them all at once.

Comment: This is incorrect, and is not the right answer. Reserved instances vs. on-demand instances are analogous to companies that allow you to pay $20/yr vs. $8/mo. Reserving instances means that you've locked-in a price, but you pay money up-front to secure that price. On-demand is, well, on-demand.

Comment: @RyanParman: looking at your profile I guess you know what you're talking about, however... are you sure you're not confusing "reserved instances" and `ReservationInfoType` API responses, aka `boto.ec2.instance.Reservation`?

Comment: Good point; I may be. Since Mitch (author of boto) works at AWS, I'd ask on the [official forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=132). Barring that, you might [file an issue](https://github.com/boto/boto) on GitHub. Then again, if I've made the mistake that @thg435 says I may have, then he may very well be right. My bad. :o

Comment: Did anyone ever open a GH issue about the `boto.ec2.instance.Reservation` documentation?  It seems it could state something more useful than "_Represents a Reservation response object._" .  Edit, there's this, but it's closed: https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/3217

Comment: Working with the EC2 console, the response I receive indicates that all manually launched instances share one reservation, even though they were launched at different times, use different hardware, etc.

Comment: Added a request for documentation: https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/3948

Answer (score 10):

From the [boto docs](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ec2_tut.html):

> A reservation corresponds to a command to start instances. You can see
>   what instances are associated with a reservation:

```
>>> instances = reservations[0].instances
>>> instances
[Instance:i-00000000]
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an interesting thread and comments from [Ryan Parman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/228514/ryan-parman) & [Rose Perrone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365298/rose-perrone) -- I may ask Mitch about the history at re:Invent later this year (2015), but if you do any normal sort of `aws ec2 describe-instances` (or the equivalent from boto, sdks, etc.) you'll see all instances enumerate as "reservations" in some generic sense:

```
{
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "OwnerId": "123456789012",
            "ReservationId": "r-9aa12345",
            "Groups": [],
            "Instances": [
```

Within that data is a `ReservationId` of a `r-12345bc8` value type, but nowhere does that correspond to reservations that you pay for to lock in the lower rate (a billing convenience, not an actual type of instance that you spin up). So my hunch is this is an interesting little residue of when they first created the system -- every instance needed to "reserve" a slot in which to run. Only later did they come up with a pricing model that used the same term.

But again, that's just a guess.

It would appear there is clearly an overlap of two meanings of the word here, that do not appear to be related to one another.