# What is the role of the Reservation class in the AWS EC2 Java SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

When running a `DescribeInstancesRequest` I get a list of reservations. Each reservation contains a list of security groups and a list of instances.

So my question is: What criteria are instances grouped in reservations and can I count on the security groups returned by the reservation being the security groups of the instances in the reservation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of 'Reservations' in Amazon EC2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618825/what-is-the-purpose-of-reservations-in-amazon-ec2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reservation is basically a set of instances. These instances can share the same reservation ID if you launch them together.

Amazon documentations:

> reservation-id - The ID of the instance's reservation. A reservation
>   ID is created any time you launch an instance. A reservation ID has a
>   one-to-one relationship with an instance launch request, but can be
>   associated with more than one instance if you launch multiple
>   instances using the same launch request.

When launching an instance, you can launch multiple instances with one launch request. These instances then belong to one reservation. A reservation can be understood as an atomic launch of one or many instances.

Do not mistake **reservations** with **reserved instances**. These are completely different concepts.

As for your other question: Yes, the security group matches the group of each instance in the reservation (all belong to the same security groups).